# ISP-provided router sending constant ARP requests

Tags: router, wireshark, arp

A few weeks ago I changed my ISP provider and router at home. It is a small network (less than 10 devices). From a user perspective everything seems to work correctly, nothing notable.

However, today I ran a Wireshark capture from one of the computers of the network (connected through WiFi), and I observed something suspicious:

[image: cap. 1]

[image: cap. 2]

The source is always the default gateway, the router my ISP gave me. I have checked the MAC and it coincides.

Things I noted:

- The ARP requests go up to 192.168.1.255 and then start again at 192.168.1.1, at a continuous rate of around 10 requests per second. That is, the router is continuously ARP scanning the whole private address range. Apparently, this goes on forever. I think this is not normal behaviour, or is it? Can it be just a "feature" of the router?
- As you can see, there is a pattern in the requests. Two requests per IP, in groups of 2 frames, one 56 bytes, the other 60 bytes. For the ones of 60 bytes Wireshark reports an "expert info" with security level "Note". The message is: "Expert Info (Note/Protocol): Didn't find padding of zeros, and an undecoded trailer exists. There may be padding of non-zeros.".
- Maybe something else I missed.
- I called my ISP and they say everything seems OK (?).

How to proceed from here?

Comment: Why is this "suspicious"? Did your other router not do this? Have you ruled out that this might be normal? Do you know what a router does when it receives a broadcast packet?

Comment: Have you checked: https://serverfault.com/questions/400484/extremely-high-arp-flooding-from-the-router

Comment: I think this is suspicious because from what I have studied about ARP protocol, ARP requests usually originate when a new device is trying to join a network, when devices change network configuration, when new services are setup or such situations. But this is not the case. The router is constantly polling the whole network, which does not seem very efficient and I see no reason why this is happening. I might be wrong though, maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I have checked the link you provide. I think the case described there is different in a couple of ways. First, the network configuration: there is no separated switch in my setup, just a router and a few devices connected to it. Second, the ARP requests are different: they are not for one or two but for the whole address range sequentially, and the volume is much lower here (10/s than there 10000/s). Third, I provided further information about the Wireshark "expert info" in the Ethernet header.  Because of these differences I thought a new question was justified.

Comment: I think the router broadcasts the packet to the broadcast domain, is this what you mean? This alone explains the behavior? Sorry, I cannot follow.

Comment: The thing is that you are seeing a protocol for what appears to be the first time. You don't have a baseline. You assume it is a security issue because you do not understand it. I would first determine if this is normal behaviour. Look up how a wifi router handles broadcast traffic. Rule out mundane explanations before jumping to malicious reasons.

Comment: My personal knowledge or assumptions about the observations are irrelevant, please do not be distracted by them. I provided some raw observations and I ask for a precise (as precise as possible given the data) explanation about the causes, please. If you need more data just ask, I may be able to provide.

Comment: But you have assumed that this is malicious. Enough to ask ***here*** and not on the networking or SuperUser site. That's what I'm speaking to. I'm advising that you rule out mundane explanations before jumping to malicious assumptions.